# OSX: How can I recursively rename some files by prepending the name of their parent folder?

Tags: macos, command

I have this file structure:

```
files
-- folder1
---- text.json
-- folder2
---- text.json
-- folder3
---- text.json
```

I'd like to prepend the folder name before each text.json, so I would get this in the end:

```
files
-- folder1
---- folder1_text.json
-- folder2
---- folder2_text.json
-- folder3
---- folder3_text.json
```

But I have no idea how to do this..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything in bash but needed to do this task, so I wrote this mini script.

To run it, copy/paste it into the Terminal or create a `file.sh` with the code inside.

notes:
- Don't forget to replace `path` variable with your parent folder path.
- I advise you to try first with a test folder.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
path=~/Documents/yourparentfolder/
for folder in "$path"/*; do
  foldername=${folder##*/}
  for file in "$path"/"$foldername"/*; do
    filename=${file##*/}
    mv "$path"/"$foldername"/"$filename" "$path"/"$foldername"/"$foldername"_"$filename"
  done
  echo $foldername files renamed! 
done
echo finished!
```

Commented version:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# path of parent folder
path=~/Documents/yourparentfolder/

# for each folder in parent folder
for folder in "$path"/*; do

  # get folder name
  foldername=${folder##*/}

  # for each file in folder
  for file in "$path"/"$foldername"/*; do

    # get file name
    filename=${file##*/}

    # rename path/folder/filename to path/folder/folder_filename
    mv "$path"/"$foldername"/"$filename" "$path"/"$foldername"/"$foldername"_"$filename"

  done

  echo $foldername files renamed! 

done

echo finished!
```

Hope to have helped you.